# To Create dynamically tables with the same type, the same tablename and different table schema in EntityFramework

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

In myproject, There should be Product tables in `MSSQLServer` according to code-first of entityframework.

My purpose is that creating lots of Products tables in database, which are company1.Products, company2.Products, company3.Products ... etc.

When I insert companyname that is should be schemaname for table. Type of Product table is the same type for all tables.

Is there solution for this problem?

[image]

Comment: What you have created is a multi-tenant database but with different schemas for each tenant. I can't help with the entity framework side of this but the database architecture is painful to work with. You can't parameterize schema names so you can't leverage stored procedures and other types of reusable code unless you stuff them with dynamic sql. A better design for a multi-tenant database is to have a column in each table to identity the tenant (CustomerID or whatever).

Comment: Second that. You can't just map the same entity to multiple tables. You would have to create separate product entities, i.e. `Company1Product`, `Company2Product`, etc., which is obviously untenable. The better approach is to add a foreign key property to your `Product` entity that ties it to a particular `Company`.